# Autolayout table cell with image and text fields?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm looking to do a table view cell with a photo and wrapping text with auto layout. I've managed a lot with auto layout, but I'm at a loss on how to do this one.

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ┌──────────┐ ┌────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ │          │ │ Title (might wrap)                 │ │
│ │          │ └────────────────────────────────────┘ │
│ │  Photo   │ ┌────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ │          │ │ Body text. May wrap, may contain   │ │
│ │          │ │ multiple lines.                    │ │
│ │          │ └────────────────────────────────────┘ │
│ └──────────┘                                        │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

As the text expands, I want to keep the photo in the top left and expand the cell. However, the cell should never shrink below the minimum required to show the photo (with margins).

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ┌──────────┐ ┌────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ │          │ │ Title (might wrap)                 │ │
│ │          │ │ Maybe even to two lines.           │ │
│ │  Photo   │ └────────────────────────────────────┘ │
│ │          │ ┌────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ │          │ │ Body text. May wrap, may contain   │ │
│ │          │ │ multiple lines.                    │ │
│ └──────────┘ │                                    │ │
│              │ Text could require more vertical   │ │
│              │ space than the photo.              │ │
│              └────────────────────────────────────┘ │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I'm requiring iOS 8 or later.

I've tried doing this with just the three views listed, and also by putting the left item and right items in two views. Every combination I try seems to ignore the photo's minimum size.

(Btw, for anyone curious: Graphic via Monodraw.)

Comment: Did you make sure the TableView's rowHeight is `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. And did you set the estimatedRowHeight to something greater than the average image view height?

Comment: Upvote for the ASCII art ;)

Comment: Does anyone have code or a project they'd be willing to post for this solution?  I have a similar layout and have it mostly working, except I cannot get the title to wrap completely... it seems to cut off with an ellipse after an arbitrary number of characters. "Lines" is 0 and "Line Break" is "Word Wrap".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try having the following relationships:

Photo:

- width = X
- height = Y
- left = Cell + Z
- top = Cell + Z

Title:

- left = Photo + Z
- right = Cell - Z
- top = Cell + Z

the label will auto calculate the height based on content

Body:

- Left = Title
- Right = Title
- Top = Title.Bottom + Z

Cell: **(this is the important part)**

- Bottom >= (equal to or greater than) Body.Bottom + Z
- Bottom >= Photo.Bottom + Z

this will force the cell to be, at all times, either taller than the image + offset or taller than the label + offset

Comment: I've tried exactly this, but the photo doesn't hold the cell to a minimum size. I'll upload a gist in an hour.

Comment: Nevermind, you were correct. I somehow had an *extra* constraint in there that was fouling it up. My thanks. This was driving me nuts; it seemed so simple!

Comment: The only other thing I found, for anyone reading this in the future, is that `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` must exist for this to work, though returning `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is fine. (One of my targets using this view controller excluded it.)